# How can I change this ggplot code so that it works with my imported excel data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using this code and I am trying to implement my dataset AAPL which I have already imported into R from excel:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
draw_candles <- function(df, title_param, alpha_param = 1){
     df$change <- ifelse(df$Close > df$Open, "up", ifelse(df$Close < df$Open, "down", "flat"))
     
     # originally the width of the bars was calculated by FXQuantTrader with use of periodicity()', which 
     # seems to work ok only with: ‘minute’,‘hourly’, ‘daily’,‘weekly’, ‘monthly’,
     # ‘quarterly’, and ‘yearly’, but can not do 1 sec bars while we want arbitrary bar size support!-)
     # df$width <- as.numeric(periodicity(df)[1])
     # So let us instead find delta (seconds) between 1st and 2nd row and just 
     # use it for all other rows. We check 1st 3 rows to avoid larger "weekend gaps"
     width_candidates <- c(as.numeric(difftime(df$Date[2], df$Date[1]), units = "secs"),
                           as.numeric(difftime(df$Date[3], df$Date[2]), units = "secs"),
                           as.numeric(difftime(df$Date[4], df$Date[3]), units = "secs"))

     df$width_s = min(width_candidates)  # one (same) candle width (in seconds) for all the bars
     
     # define the vector of candle colours either by name or by rgb()
     #candle_colors = c("down" = "red", "up" = "green", "flat" = "blue")
     candle_colors = c("down" = rgb(192,0,0,alpha=255,maxColorValue=255), "up" = rgb(0,192,0,alpha=255,maxColorValue=255), "flat" = rgb(0,0,192,alpha=255,maxColorValue=255))
     
     # Candle chart:
     g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Date))+
         geom_linerange(aes(ymin=Low, ymax=High, colour = change), alpha = alpha_param) +  # candle whiskerss (vertical thin lines:)
         theme_bw() +
         labs(title=title_param) +
         geom_rect(aes(xmin = Date - width_s/2 * 0.9, xmax = Date + width_s/2 * 0.9, ymin = pmin(Open, Close), ymax = pmax(Open, Close), fill = change), alpha = alpha_param) +                            
            # cabdke body
         guides(fill = FALSE, colour = FALSE) +
         scale_color_manual(values = candle_colors) +  # color for line
         scale_fill_manual(values = candle_colors)     # color for candle fill  
     
     # Handle special cases: flat bar and Open == close:
     if (any(df$change == "flat")) g <- g + geom_segment(data = df[df$change == "flat",], aes(x = Date - width_s / 2 * 0.9, y = Close, yend = Close, xend = Date + width_s / 2 * 0.9, colour = change), alpha = alpha_param)
     
     g
}
 > print(draw_candles(g,AAPL))
```

My problem is that every time I try to print out the graph, I get this error:

> Error in ifelse(df$Close > df$Open, "up", ifelse(df$Close < df$Open,
> "down",  : object 'g' not found

And I have no idea how to fix it or what I am doing wrong.

```
dput(head(AAPL, 20))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(345427200, 345686400, 345772800, 
345859200, 345945600, 346032000, 346291200, 346377600, 346464000, 
346636800, 346896000, 346982400, 347068800, 347241600, 347500800, 
347587200, 347673600, 347760000, 347846400, 348105600), tzone = "UTC", class 
= c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Open = c("0.12834799999999999", "0.12221", "0.11328100000000001", 
"0.115513", "0.118862", "0.12611600000000001", "0.13225400000000001", 
"0.13783500000000001", "0.145089", "0.15848200000000001", "0.160714", 
"0.15736600000000001", "0.15290200000000001", "0.15401799999999999", 
"0.151228", "0.14453099999999999", "0.13839299999999999", "0.135603", 
"0.14229900000000001", "0.14229900000000001"), High = 
c("0.12890599999999999", 
"0.12221", "0.11328100000000001", "0.11607099999999999", "0.11942", 
"0.12667400000000001", "0.13281299999999999", "0.13839299999999999", 
"0.145647", "0.15903999999999999", "0.161272", "0.15736600000000001", 
"0.15290200000000001", "0.15513399999999999", "0.151228", 
"0.14453099999999999", 
"0.13839299999999999", "0.135603", "0.14285700000000001", 
"0.14229900000000001"
), Low = c("0.12834799999999999", "0.121652", "0.112723", "0.115513", 
"0.118862", "0.12611600000000001", "0.13225400000000001", 
"0.13783500000000001", 
"0.145089", "0.15848200000000001", "0.160714", "0.156808", 
"0.15234400000000001", 
"0.15401799999999999", "0.15067", "0.14397299999999999", 
"0.13783500000000001", 
"0.135045", "0.14229900000000001", "0.141183"), Close = 
c("0.12834799999999999", 
"0.121652", "0.112723", "0.115513", "0.118862", "0.12611600000000001", 
"0.13225400000000001", "0.13783500000000001", "0.145089", 
"0.15848200000000001", 
"0.160714", "0.156808", "0.15234400000000001", "0.15401799999999999", 
"0.15067", "0.14397299999999999", "0.13783500000000001", "0.135045", 
"0.14229900000000001", "0.141183"), `Adj Close` = c("0.101261", 
"0.095977999999999994", "0.088933999999999999", "0.091134999999999994", 
"0.093776999999999999", "0.099500000000000005", "0.10434300000000001", 
"0.108746", "0.114469", "0.12503500000000001", "0.12679599999999999", 
"0.12371500000000001", "0.12019299999999999", "0.121513", 
"0.11887200000000001", 
"0.11358799999999999", "0.108746", "0.106544", "0.11226800000000001", 
"0.111387"), Volume = c("469033600", "175884800", "105728000", 
"86441600", "73449600", "48630400", "37363200", "46950400", "48003200", 
"55574400", "93161600", "68880000", "35750400", "21660800", "35728000", 
"45158400", "55686400", "39827200", "21504000", "23699200")), row.names = 
c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Try `draw_candles(AAPL, "TITLE")`. The functions takes a dataframe as the first argument, a title for the plot and a alpha param with a default.

Comment: @stefan, That sadly did not work. It is saying that 'g' and 'AAPL' are not found. Could it be a problem with my data?

Comment: Hi Drake-Payta. Hm. Hard to tell wether this is related to your data or the code. Therefore: Could you provide a snippet of your data? Best way to do this is by typing `dput(head(AAPL, 20))` (which gives the first 20 rows of your data) into the console. Then copy and paste the output starting with `structure(...` into your post.

Comment: structure(c("0.12834799999999999", "0.12221", "0.11328100000000001", 
"0.115513", "0.12890599999999999", "0.12221", "0.11328100000000001", 
"0.11607099999999999", "0.12834799999999999", "0.121652", "0.112723", 
"0.115513", "0.12834799999999999", "0.121652", "0.112723", "0.115513", 
"0.101261", "0.095977999999999994", "0.088933999999999999", "0.091134999999999994", 
"469033600", "175884800", "105728000", "86441600"), .Dim = c(4L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", 
"Adj Close", "Volume"))

Comment: dput(head(AAPL, 20)) was to long to paste and comment. For that reason, I had to type: dput(head(AAPL, 4)).

Comment: You could have added it as an edit to your post instead of pasting it into the comment. (; I will have a look.

Comment:  oh haha. Thank you. Appreciate it!

Comment: First issue. Your data is a matrix and not a data.frame, i.e. do `AAPL <- as.data.frame(AAPL)`. Second issue. Your data has no `Date` column. Without that the function will not work. So. The issue is related to your data. (;

Comment: ... and inside the function I guess that in the line starting with `if (any(AAPL$change == "flat"))` it should be `if (any(df$change == "flat"))` and `g <- ggplot(AAPL, aes(x=Date))` should be `g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Date))`.

Comment: I turned it into a data.frame as well as adding a Date column and it appears to still be bugging out. I will edit my post to show dput(head(AAPL, 20))

Comment: oh okay, let me try that

Comment: With the changes it should work. Just checked.

Comment: Everything seems to check out, though, I keep on getting: Error: unexpected symbol in:
"    
} print"                                                                            and I have no idea what that means.

Comment: I just added a reprex as an answer. Check it out. The final error looks like a typo. But not sure were it came from.

Comment: It was a typo, I found it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's wrong. So now the full reprex.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)

draw_candles <- function(df, title_param, alpha_param = 1) {
  df$change <- ifelse(df$Close > df$Open, "up", ifelse(df$Close < df$Open, "down", "flat"))

  # originally the width of the bars was calculated by FXQuantTrader with use of periodicity()', which
  # seems to work ok only with: 'minute','hourly', 'daily','weekly', 'monthly',
  # 'quarterly', and 'yearly', but can not do 1 sec bars while we want arbitrary bar size support!-)
  # df$width <- as.numeric(periodicity(df)[1])
  # So let us instead find delta (seconds) between 1st and 2nd row and just
  # use it for all other rows. We check 1st 3 rows to avoid larger "weekend gaps"
  width_candidates <- c(
    as.numeric(difftime(df$Date[2], df$Date[1]), units = "secs"),
    as.numeric(difftime(df$Date[3], df$Date[2]), units = "secs"),
    as.numeric(difftime(df$Date[4], df$Date[3]), units = "secs")
  )

  df$width_s <- min(width_candidates) # one (same) candle width (in seconds) for all the bars

  # define the vector of candle colours either by name or by rgb()
  # candle_colors = c("down" = "red", "up" = "green", "flat" = "blue")
  candle_colors <- c("down" = rgb(192, 0, 0, alpha = 255, maxColorValue = 255), "up" = rgb(0, 192, 0, alpha = 255, maxColorValue = 255), "flat" = rgb(0, 0, 192, alpha = 255, maxColorValue = 255))

  # Candle chart:
  g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) +
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin = Low, ymax = High, colour = change), alpha = alpha_param) + # candle whiskerss (vertical thin lines:)
    theme_bw() +
    labs(title = title_param) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = Date - width_s / 2 * 0.9, xmax = Date + width_s / 2 * 0.9, ymin = pmin(Open, Close), ymax = pmax(Open, Close), fill = change), alpha = alpha_param) +
    # cabdke body
    guides(fill = FALSE, colour = FALSE) +
    scale_color_manual(values = candle_colors) + # color for line
    scale_fill_manual(values = candle_colors) # color for candle fill

  # Handle special cases: flat bar and Open == close:
  if (any(df$change == "flat")) g <- g + geom_segment(data = df[df$change == "flat", ], aes(x = Date - width_s / 2 * 0.9, y = Close, yend = Close, xend = Date + width_s / 2 * 0.9, colour = change), alpha = alpha_param)

  g
}

draw_candles(AAPL, "Hello")
```

[image]